# What does bad color sequence mean in Python turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am using python turtle for a project where I need turtle to draw characters. However, when I try to use the RGB value for a color, I keep getting an error message. The input is:

```
turtle.color((151,2,1))
```

followed by a series of movements. However, when I run the program I get this message:

```
File "C:/Users/Larry/Desktop/tests.py", line 5, in center
turtle.color((151,2,1))
File "<string>", line 1, in color
File "C:\Python33\lib\turtle.py", line 2208, in color
pcolor = self._colorstr(pcolor)
File "C:\Python33\lib\turtle.py", line 2688, in _colorstr
return self.screen._colorstr(args)
File "C:\Python33\lib\turtle.py", line 1158, in _colorstr
raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color sequence: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (151, 2, 1)
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Run `screen.colormode(255)` and it should work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.pencolor):

> Each of r, g, and b must be in the range 0..colormode, where colormode is either 1.0 or 255 (see [colormode()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.colormode)).

Your colormode is probably set to 1.0, so either the individual color coordinates need to be floats in the range 0 to 1, or you need to set the colormode to 255.

Answer (score 7):

A very short and simplified answer is, it means the value passed to the pencolor() method has not been previously set via the Screen object method colormode().

A screen object must be created. And then, the color mode must be set. Thus, making it possible for the turtle pen to accept a tuple class object which contains a number ranging from 0 - 255. `(255, 0, 20)` *for example*. Why? Because there is more than one way of setting the color mode.

e.g.

```
from turtle import Turtle
from turtle import Screen

# Creating a turtle object
bert = Turtle()

# Creating the screen object
screen = Screen()

# Setting the screen color-mode
screen.colormode(255)

# Changing the color of the pen the turtle carries
bert.pencolor(255, 0, 0)

# 'Screen object loop to prevent the window from closing without command'
screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1):

you get this error in case of like you are generating a random color using a function and you are using the random module and then returning a tuple of 3 random integers, and pass this tuple color function
you can fix this issue by writing this turtle.colormode(255)

use this code

```
import random
import turtle

from turtle import Turtle
turtle.colormode(255)
tim = Turtle()
tim.speed("fastest")
direction = [90,  270]
#colours = ["CornflowerBlue", "DarkOrchid", "IndianRed", "DeepSkyBlue", "LightSeaGreen", "wheat", "SlateGray", "SeaGreen"]
tim.pensize(5)

def random_color():
    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)
    random_color = (r, g, b)
    return random_color


while True:
    move = random.choice(direction)
    tim.forward(40)
    tim.color(random_color())
    tim.left(move)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to import colormode function

```
from turtle import Turtle
from turtle import colormode
from turtle import Screen

tim = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
colormode(255)

tim.pencolor(151,2,1)
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to existing answers

Answer (score -1):

you will get this error in case you are generating a random color using a function and you are using the random module and then returning a tuple of 3 random integers, and pass this tuple color function
you can fix this issue by writing this turtle.colormode(255)

use this code

```
import random
import turtle

from turtle import Turtle
turtle.colormode(255)
tim = Turtle()
tim.speed("fastest")
direction = [90,  270]
#colours = ["CornflowerBlue", "DarkOrchid", "IndianRed", "DeepSkyBlue", "LightSeaGreen", "wheat", "SlateGray", "SeaGreen"]
tim.pensize(5)

def random_color():
    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)
    random_color = (r, g, b)
    return random_color


while True:
    move = random.choice(direction)
    tim.forward(40)
    tim.color(random_color())
    tim.left(move)
```

Comment: [Posted twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70413881/6243352) and doesn't really add anything other answers don't already discuss--please try to avoid adding noise to the thread. Thanks.