# turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm getting a colorfill error for my Python turtle graphics code, but I don't understand why. The method `t.fillcolor()` should accept 3 values as the r,g,b values for the fillcolor of a turtle shape, where `t` is a turtle. However, any three values in the method produce an error.

This is how the `t.fillcolor()` is explained in my book:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
from turtle import Turtle,Screen
#might want to use:
#from turtle import *
from random import randint

def hexagon(t, length):
    """Draws a hexagon with the given length."""
    for count in range(6):
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(60)

def radialPattern(t, n, length, shape):
    """Draws a radial pattern of n shapes with the given length."""
    for count in range(n):
        shape(t, length)
        t.left(360 / n)

screen = Screen() #create a screen object
screen.setup(width=600,height=400) #size
screen.bgcolor("lightblue")
screen.title("My turtle")
t = Turtle()

#added code here:
t.fillcolor(20,75,153)
t.begin_fill()
radialPattern(t,5,30,hexagon)
t.end_fill()



screen.exitonclick() #keep the screen open until user closes it
```

The code execution starts at line `screen = Screen() #create a screen object`

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Turtle for final.py", line 25, in <module>
    t.fillcolor(20,75,153)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\turtle.py", line 2289, in fillcolor
    color = self._colorstr(args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\turtle.py", line 2697, in _colorstr
    return self.screen._colorstr(args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\turtle.py", line 1167, in _colorstr
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color sequence: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (20, 75, 153)
```

I've gotten this method to work properly plenty of times. It's just not working here and I don't understand why.

If someone could help me out, I would appreciate it.

Comment: That error shouldn't be possible with those values.  I have to suspect that you've somehow modified the previous line in `turtle.py` from the Python standard library, which should read `if not ((0 <= r <= 255) and (0 <= g <= 255) and (0 <= b <= 255)):`.

Comment: Do you think the turtle.py module could have gotten corrupted? I've never opened it.

Comment: No wait, I didn't look far enough up from the error location.  It wants values in the 0.0 - 1.0 range by default; if you want to use 0 - 255 values, you have to call `screen.colormode(255)` first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does bad color sequence mean in python turtle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778324/what-does-bad-color-sequence-mean-in-python-turtle)

Comment: It was a colormode error, thanks. I had moved the turtle.cfg that had this information in it, and that's what created the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To use rgb color mode, turtle needs to be set up rgb color mode. By default, the color mode is set up 0 - 1.  For setting up, tap the turtle (or its aliases) module and set the colormode with turtle.colormode(255) and then you can use the rgb tuple values. It won't work if you tap on the constructor.